# Is it possible to apply a particular CSS to a textbox in case it cannot pass a RequiredFieldValidator?

Tags: asp.net, .net, css, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

Is it possible in ASP.NET to enforce a Requiredfieldvalidator control to add a CssClass to a TextBox in case it fails the validation?

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtSomeInput" runat="server" />
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" Text="*" ErrorMessage="This is required." ControlToValidate="txtSomeInput" 
<!-- Do something so that if validation fails, add CssClass 'failed' to txtSomeInput; possible? -->
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can achieve that using `CustomValidator` with code-behind validation logic using `CssClass` property.
- Or inherit `RequiredFieldValidator` and extend validation failure reaction

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to use [this example](http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=362).

It relies on altering and using some of the javascript code generated by asp validation controls and has the advantage of being usable with all kinds of validation controls and does not require a post back (if client validation fails no postback is made to alter the class of the text box).

best of luck,